# How can I turn full capital words strings into ucwords in php?

Tags: php

I have been really trying to do some pretty basic work in PHP as I am beginner to PHP but I wasn't really able to achieve my goal.
What I want to do is that I have strings like..!
Mixed Types :

```
THIS IS A SENTENCE
tHis Is a SEnTenCe
```

I really tried with `ucwords` function in php but that didn't gave the exact result as ucwords focus just on first alphabets of every word and do not focus on other remaining characters in word..What I want really is to get some sort of this fixed type of strings from each and every mixed type of strings..!

Like :

```
This Is A Sentence
```

Or May be I didn't check it properly..So if anyone can guide me in the right path.That would be great.!

Comment: what if you have a string such as `THIS IS A SENTENCE FROM the Us-of-A`? `ucwords(strtolower` will fail.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well..What will be the solution then for extra informations?

Comment: I did but can you just post that please..will be really helpful..

Comment: Well @Fred-ii- What algorithm would you propose that can determine that the `S` in Us-of-A should be capitalized.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  @AbraCadaver  Would it help to do `explode` and then use `foreach` to get result in Capitalized..! ? For Us-of-A ?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I was merely pointing it out that it would fail if the OP were faced with characters as such (I should have preceeded it with the word "sidenote") ;-). It will require some pretty fancy regex to do this. Umar, I don't know why you unaccepted AbraCadaver's answer. The question should be marked as solved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Understood.  `Us of A` would be nearly impossible to get US.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Pretty much. TBH, I spent the better part of an hour last night trying to figure it out. I thought I had a piece of code already in my library, but alas; I didn't. I upvoted your answer, and hoping OP will re-accept, *cheers*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to lowercase first:

```
$string = ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$l = 'tHis Is a SEnTenCe';
echo ucwords(strtolower($l));
?>
```

Result

```
This Is A Sentence
```